# Кросс компиляция для арм линукс Segmentation fault arm920t

Tags: linux, arm, segmentation-fault, кросс-компиляция

Я новичок в разработке под arm. Возникла следующая проблема.
Есть плата на процессоре arm920t (AT91RM9200), на ней крутиться вот такой Линукс

```
root@test-device:/home/andy # uname -a
Linux test-device 2.6.21.201509.01 #13 Wed Jun 22 11:06:51 EEST 2016 armv4tl unknown
```

На виртуалке у меня стоит Ubutu 18.04 в качестве машины для кросс-компиляции
Там установлены пакеты для кросс-компиляции из репозитория Ubuntu
1. arm-linux-gnueabi
2. arm-none-eabi

собираю простейший hello world

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Сборку и компиляцию выполняю каждым из пакетов

```
supersonic@ubuntu-vBox:~$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o hello_arm hello.c -static
supersonic@ubuntu-vBox:~$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -o hello_arm_none-eabi hello.c --specs=nosys.specs
```

В обоих случаях создается свой бинарный исполняемый файл
Утилиты readelf и file говорят про них следующее:

```
1. (собран пакетом arm-linux-gnueabi)

    supersonic@ubuntu-vBox:~$ readelf -h hello_arm
    ELF Header:
      Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
      Class:                             ELF32
      Data:                              2's complement, little endian
      Version:                           1 (current)
      OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
      ABI Version:                       0
      Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
      Machine:                           ARM
      Version:                           0x1
      Entry point address:               0x101a0
      Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
      Start of section headers:          501788 (bytes into file)
      Flags:                             0x5000200, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
      Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
      Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
      Number of program headers:         7
      Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
      Number of section headers:         30
      Section header string table index: 29
    supersonic@ubuntu-vBox:~$ 

    supersonic@ubuntu-vBox:~$ file hello_arm
    hello_arm: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=15d06e43de8c8d13d7e0110e311532a9187ca9e5, not stripped

2. (собран пакетом arm-none-eabi)
supersonic@ubuntu-vBox:~$ readelf -h hello_arm_none-eabi 
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8148
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          186056 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000200, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         3
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         27
  Section header string table index: 24

supersonic@ubuntu-vBox:~$ file hello_arm_none-eabi 
hello_arm_none-eabi: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Заливаю через sftp на таргет машину эти файлы, ставлю им права на выполнение

```
root@test-device:/home/andy # chmod +x hello_arm
root@test-device:/home/andy # chmod +x hello_arm_none-eabi
```

При попытке запуска обоих бинарников на целевой платформе, получаю следующие результаты

```
1. (собран пакетом arm-linux-gnueabi)
root@test-device:/home/andy # ./hello_arm
Illegal instruction

2. (собран пакетом arm-none-eabi)
root@test-device:/home/andy # ./hello_arm_none-eabi
Segmentation fault
```

На таргет машине, есть бинарники которые там запускаются и работают, но человек который их собирал делал это
еще лет 5 назад и с тех пор во 1х никто там ничего не поддерживал и во 2х связи либо какого то еще контакта с ним больше нет.

Вот, что говорят утилиты readelf и file про бинарник который там запускается корректно

```
supersonic@ubuntu-vBox:~$ readelf -h /media/share_rw/MTXReader 
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            ARM
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xab1c
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          681968 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x2, GNU EABI, <unknown>
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         38
  Section header string table index: 35

supersonic@ubuntu-vBox:~$ file /media/share_rw/MTXReader 
/media/share_rw/MTXReader: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (ARM), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.0.10, with debug_info, not stripped
```

Явно видны различия между ними в заголовках и их характеристиках, но как бы я не пытался играться с опциями, выходит один и тот же результат

Пробовал собирать с передачей опций в оба сборочных пакета инфу о процессоре и его архитектуре

```
1. supersonic@ubuntu-vBox:~$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o hello_arm hello.c -static -mcpu=arm920t -march=armv4t
2. supersonic@ubuntu-vBox:~$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -o hello_arm_none-eabi hello.c --specs=nosys.specs -mcpu=arm920t -march=armv4t
```

Точно такие же результаты

Был бы рад за любую помощь в этом вопросе, я только начинаю осваивать этот мир встраиваемых систем. С Уважением!

Comment: [ но человек который их собирал делал это еще лет 5 назад и с тех пор во 1х никто там ничего не поддерживал и во 2х связи либо какого то еще контакта с ним больше нет.] Скажите владельцам бизнеса, что такими кадрами нельзя разбрасываться. :-)

Comment: Навскидку ответ не скажу. Попробуйте дизассемблировать: objdump -d, рабочий вариант и тот, что с illegal instruction. Глазами пробегитесь, сюда куски выложите, что-нибудь прояснится. Arm920t ядро мне в принципе знакомо...

Comment: Сдается, что ключевой момент в "UNIX - System V / Version5 EABI" у вас vs "ARM / GNU EABI" в рабочем варианте. В эту сторону и копать. Я так понял, что кросс-платф. пакеты вы взяли в общем-то от балды? От рабочего бинарника остался только сам бинарник? никаких следов исходников, version control'ов, makefiles - вообще ничего?

Comment: Да, к сожалению ничего не осталось, тот проект похерели уже давно, я дизасм листинг смогу только в понедельник скинуть. По поводу кросс-платформ пакетов, если вы имеете в виду тул-чейны для компиляции и линковки, я брал их с репозитория Юбунты, как советую практически во всех статьях для арм разработки. Удручает лишь тот момент, что на текущий 2019 год, большинство статей морально устарело и множество пакетов для кросс компиляции уже просто не существую на сайтах тех сообществ

Comment: Бывает. А в чём ваша-то задача не очень понятно? .. Тут за чат наказывают, а есть ли тут какая-то личка я не удосужился узнать :) Короче, если что я готов помочь, чем могу, в схожей области работаю. Но лучше, наверное, или в личке или по мылу продолжать. Пока что похоже, что тулзы у вас не те, а какие были "те" - это надо еще помучиться. Удачи.

Comment: tum_ если есть возможность добавьте меня в скайп supersonic313371

Comment: Скайп - не очень, но как крайний вариант сгодится. я тут видел люди в какой-то "чат" переходят, чтоб правила не нарушать (или модераторы их переносят). Попробуйте разобраться, если время позволяет, я на сегодня, наверное, всё. Да, обращаться надо @tum_ - тогда система мне уведомление пришлет..

Comment: @tum_ ok, вам удобнее через почту ?

Comment: Да почта норм, но я свою здесь не напишу.

Comment: @tum_ тогда если не сложно ответьте в скайпе который я написал выше, там обменяемся почтой

Comment: Да, это и был "крайний вариант". Завтра попробую.

Comment: по идее `arm-linux-gnueabi -march=armv4t` и всё, не?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Говорит, пробовал (внизу ориг поста написано). Меня вот "-static" смущает, проверить бы по какому пути он libc находит, может фигня какая линкуется. Люди советуют "-Xlinker -static /path/to/libc.a" с явным путем попробовать. И на всякий "-Wall", может подскажет чего.

Comment: @tum_, да, пропустил... со статической линковкой, кстати, проблема не только в том, где он её находит, а ещё в том, с каким `march`'ем она сама была собрана... возможно поможет банально слинковать его в динамику и надеяться на лучшее...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Угу. В пнд на работе посмотрит. Продолжение следует, в общем.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, в динамику смогу только завтра попробовать, но очень сомневаюсь что оно заведётся ((